# Make gnus display inline html images by default

Tags: gnus, html, images, w3m

How can I make gnus display inline images from html articles by default?

A command exists to display them on a per-article basis:
`gnus-article-show-images`

however I would like this behavior automatically.

Google searches turn up articles dating all the way back to 2002, utilizing out-dated since removed variables. I've also found forum posts and gits with dotfiles only as old as 2015 with the out-dated variable:
`mm-inline-text-html-with-images`

I cannot find this in any documentation, nor have I successfully found an exhaustive changelog (or any real changelog, for that matter) of emacs or gnus, that I can find when this variable was removed, or canonical evidence it ever existed, as emacs/gnus does not recognize this variable.

Both inhibit images variables are `nil`

Emacs Version: `25.3.1`
Gnus Version: `5.13`

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're talking about inline images which are included within the message, or inline images referenced via an external URL?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the difference. This issue mostly pertains to html emails, such as a sales catalog emailed from newegg, these appear to be URLs as far as I can tell, and are displayed by default in other email clients, or displayed in w3m/gnus-w3m via `gnus-article-show-images`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `gnus-blocked-images`.

Note that displaying images which need to be fetched via a URL means that the sender can know when you're reading the message, so it introduces a serious privacy issue, which is why it's disabled by default when reading email messages.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that line in the documentation, right underneath setting the w3m browser no less! +1, many thanks!